# Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> The project 'FeedBack' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Fix plugin version and sync project
>
> The project 'FeedBack' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

//Module: app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "burpp.av.feedback"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.appsee:appsee-android:2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
}
```

Comment: What version of AS are you using? You need to use latest one in order you to use latest plugin with crashlytics.

Comment: Android Studio 2.1.2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to insert `classpath` dependencies inside `buildscript` block.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    // move it here
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

Comment: @AbdulGaffar Accept the answer if it was the right one

Comment: I am facing same Problem In my case when I am adding Volley every time creating a error in android studio

Comment: If above is not working than check your app level dependency may be by mistake you add any classpath dependency in your dependency,Just remove it. :)