# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIMtJ.jpg)An error with Gradle in android studio.
It says: ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.3.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 2):

Add maven in your build.gradel file

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
}
```

Sync code again.

Answer (score 0):

The support libraries are now available through Google's `Maven` repository.

**Step 1**: Open the `build.gradle` file of your project.

**Step 2**: Make sure that the repositories section includes a `maven` section with the https://maven.google.com `url` in it.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // here
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation"com.android.support:support-core-utils:23.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks,After that it shows this massege:
ERROR: Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :

Comment: Yes,Now,I got this massege :

ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:
The project 'Just-Java-master' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.0 and sync project

The project 'Just-Java-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672099/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-classpath       OR this :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838173/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-implementation

Comment: On right,
now this message:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Just-Java-master'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle you have to add:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin-DSL version:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven(url= "https://maven.google.com")
    }
}
```